# Valorize Base Class variable in SubClass

Tags: c#

I have one class inherit by one.
How can access and valorize one base attribute?

**Class.cs**

```
public class Class
{
    public int example;
}
```

**SubClass1.cs**

```
public class SubClass1 : Class
{
    Class.example = 10;  //This one not work. How to?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This invocation:

```
Class.example = 10;
```

implies that `example` is a `static` member of `Class`, which it is not.  It's also trying to set the value in the manner of a member declaration, which in this case is incorrect since the member is *already declared* in the parent class.

To set a value to the member upon instantiation of the `SubClass1` type, simply set it in the constructor:

```
public class SubClass1 : Class
{
    public SubClass1()
    {
        example = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Many Thanks!